# I got an SQL error running this code: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.teachername
FROM teacher t
WHERE 5 > (SELECT E.studentid
FROM Class C, Enrolled E
WHERE C.classname = E.classname
AND C.teacherid = t.teacherid)
```

I never got this issue and I have no idea what's causing it. An explanation would be helpful.

Comment: The subquery returns more than one row and MySQL is not sure which row to compare with 5.

Comment: The error is because the subquery is allows to only return at most one row. When more than one row is returned, we expect the error. It looks like maybe we want to return a count of rows. But that's just a guess. If that's the intent, then the simplest fix is to replace `E.studentid` with  either `COUNT(E.studentid)` or `COUNT(DISTINCT E.studentid)`.  The `COUNT` aggregate function will cause a single row to be returned.  (There are other, better, ways to write a query to return an equivalent result.)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare the number `5` with the result of a query that returns (more than 1) `studentid`s and this does not make sense.
I suspect that maybe you want to count the `studentid`s, so maybe something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.teachername
FROM teacher t
WHERE 5 > (
  SELECT COUNT(E.studentid)
  FROM Class C INNER JOIN Enrolled E
  ON C.classname = E.classname
  WHERE C.teacherid = t.teacherid
)
```

I also changed to a proper JOIN inside the query.
Maybe `COUNT(DISTINCT E.studentid)` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return the required results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.teachername
FROM teacher t
INNER JOIN Class C on C.teacherid = t.teacherid
INNER JOIN Entrolled E on C.classname = E.classname
WHERE   E.studentid < 5
```

If you need the count, as suggested, the query would be:

```
SELECT t.teachername
FROM teacher t
INNER JOIN Class C on C.teacherid = t.teacherid
INNER JOIN Entrolled E on C.classname = E.classname
GROUP BY t.teachername
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT E.studentid) < 5
```

Comment: I think in your example it should be `<6`